# soundconverter encoding to Opus format fails

Tags: 16.04, convert, soundconverter, ogg-opus

Since installing 16.04 I'm unable to convert wav files to the opus format. This is the error message I get:

```
GStreamer error when creating pipeline

gst_parse_error: no property "cbr" in element "opusenc0" (2)
```

I'm using soundConverter version 2.9.0-beta1 with Gstreamer 1.8.2.0

Comment: Try closing Soundconverter and then running the following: `mv -v ~/.gconf/apps/SoundConverter ~/.gconf/apps/SoundConverter_bak` and then restart SoundConverter. This should reset to defaults and may be enough...

Comment: Thanks @andrew-46 for the suggestion. I tried to reset gconf configuration using the method suggested but that did not solve the issue.

Comment: This did the trick. Thank you @andrew.46! This is clearly a bug and should be sent upstream. Maybe you know how to handle that?

Comment: Great news :). The fix is in SoundConverter git so just a matter of time until it gets to Ubuntu. In the meantime this question and its answer will be useful for others!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a [known bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/soundconverter/+bug/1097610) with SoundConverter and newer versions of GStreamer which has [a fix](https://github.com/kassoulet/soundconverter/commit/b65d4f0bde2439e48dc4ee2021cb22675fc8ce1f) in git. The tricky work with `sed` below *duplicates* the upstream patch which is not yet present in the Ubuntu package:

**1. Fix:**

Copy and paste the *entire* code below into a Terminal window:

```
sudo sed -i_bak 's/opusenc bitrate=%s cbr=false/opusenc bitrate=%s bitrate-type=vbr/' \
/usr/share/soundconverter/python/soundconverter/gstreamer.py
```

**2. Reverse the fix:**

If you would like to reverse this simple hack run the following *single command*:

```
sudo mv -v /usr/share/soundconverter/python/soundconverter/gstreamer.py_bak \
/usr/share/soundconverter/python/soundconverter/gstreamer.py
```

And SoundConverter will be returned to its original state :).

References:

- [Launchpad Bug: Opus files are encoded in hard-CBR](https://bugs.launchpad.net/soundconverter/+bug/1097610)
- [SoundConveter Commit: Fix opus vbr setting](https://github.com/kassoulet/soundconverter/commit/b65d4f0bde2439e48dc4ee2021cb22675fc8ce1f)